# Is there a word that can be said instead of saying "I said your name to get your attention"?

Tags: word-request

Is there a word that can be said instead of saying:

> "I said your name to get your attention"?

For example:

Q: "where's our friend?"

A: "He's over there I'll say his name to get his attention (so that he'll come to where I am)"

not by making a phone call

Comment: Are you talking about getting someone's attention in a public place (rather than calling to them in a room)? There's an expression 'to page someone' for when an announcement is made such as 'Can Mr X. please come to the information desk".

Comment: but I'm taking about doing that to a friend in a public place so that he'll come to where I am.

Comment: Well, it's assumed that you are waiting for them at the desk!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*to call someone* means *to ask someone to come to you*

If you can *call* someone, you ask them to come to you because you need them. You can call them **over** (it just stresses that they have to cover some distance to get to your location).

> Wait a minute, I will call him over.
>
> Let's call him over... JAAAAMES!!

If there is an emergency and you need them urgently, you can call them **out**.

> We had to call out a doctor.

Comment: isn't call only used when I'm on the phone? What can I say if for example I want to get their attenction by saying their name when they are in a public park and not by making a phone call

Comment: @coolguy yes, **to call** can mean **to phone**, but it's not the main meaning of the word. Have a look here https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/call

Comment: thanks,I asked this question because couldn't find it on the cambrige dictionary

Comment: @coolguy https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/call scroll down a bit until you find "She called me over to where she was sitting."